# Why doesn't SwiftUI onTapGesture always work

Tags: swiftui, gesture-recognition

The onTapGesture in SWiftUI doesn't work reliably.  This example shows the problem, which is that sometimes when you tap on a cell, the background changes to grey as it should, and another time an adjacent cell changes and at other time nothing happens at all.  Any ideas why?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cellFg: [[Color]] = [
        [.clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear],
        [.clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear],
        [.clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear],
        [.clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear],
        [.clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear],
        [.clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear],
        [.clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear],
        [.clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear],
        [.clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear, .clear]
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ForEach(0..<9) { row in
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ForEach(0..<9) { column in
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(cellFg[row][column])
                            .border(Color.gray, width: 1)

                            // When you tap, it sometimes works, sometimes selects
                            // an adjacent cell and sometimes does nothing
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print("Row \(row) - Column\(column)")
                                cellFg[row][column] = .gray
                            }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Rectangle here is transparent but gesture requires content to be opaque.

Here is a fix (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

```
Rectangle()
    .foregroundColor(self.cellFg[row][column])
    .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())         // << here !!
```

the `.contentShape` make hit-testable entire frame independently of transparency.

Comment: Good tip. Helped. Found more details of why this is the case -> https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view-using-contentshape

Answer (score 3):

Add an extension to fix this problem

```
private struct ExpandAreaTap: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            content
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func expandTap(tap: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
        self.modifier(ExpandAreaTap()).onTapGesture(perform: tap)
    }
}
```